# How to update a ag-grid child component in parent component

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I create a ag-grid in a child component, when the rowData have been updated in child component, how can the parent copmonent be updated to see the new grid data?

child.html

```
<ag-grid-angular  ...></ag-grid-angular>
```

parent.html

```
<div> some other content</div>
<div>
    <child></child>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help~

Comment: Assuming you got the row modification part covered in child component. After the row data has been modified in child component you can simply add and event emitter and emit the changes to parent component.

Comment: @KelumBandara Sorry, still don't understand..., how can I emit "new grid" to the parent component? I want to update the whole <child></child> show in the parent component